# CodeIgniter3 extending Language Helper

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm using CodeIgniter 3 and I want to expand default Language Helper.

CodeIgniter by default allows with function `lang(language_key)` get a value from language file, but my language file is different.

Default language file:

```
$lang = [
    'MONTH_JANUARY' => 'January',
    'MONTH_FEBRUARY' => 'February',
];
```

My file:

```
$lang = [
    'MONTH' => [
        'JANUARY' => 'January',
        'FEBRUARY' => 'February',
    ],
];
```

I want to create a helper function with explode.

For example, using `lang('MONTH.JANUARY')` it will look for $lang['MONTH']['JANUARY'] and return 'January'.

What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use reference to walk through array

```
function lang($string) {
  $lang = [
    'MONTH' => [
        'JANUARY' => 'January',
        'FEBRUARY' => 'February',
    ],
  ];

  $p = &$lang;
  foreach(explode('.', $string) as $x) {
     if(! isset($p[$x])) {
       // key does not exist - do something
     }
     else {
       $p = &$p[$x];
     }   
  }
  return $p;
}


echo lang('MONTH.JANUARY'); // 'January'
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/958929)

Comment: Thanks this works, but what if $lang array is deeper? Like `$lang = ['DATETIME' => ['MONTH' => ['JANUARY' => 'January']]];`.

Comment: the function does not depend on "depth" of a keys list

Comment: I've added demo link. You can try